# How is a # intepreted in a Guid/UNIQUEIDENTIFIER (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a behavior I only came to learn of by mistake. A table in SQL Server has a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column and I ran a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE GuidColumn = N'2B375CD8-D210-463F-A2FD-EAFB0D643664#1'
```

The #1 at the end of the Guid got there by mistake as I had copy-pasted it from a url that was appending #1, #2, #3, and so on representing paging.

What surprised me is that the query ran just fine and I got the same result as I would get by running:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE GuidColumn = N'2B375CD8-D210-463F-A2FD-EAFB0D643664'
```

Would anyone know how the # and anything after is intepreted in such a scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is dealt with explicitly on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

It doesn't *mean* anything - SQL server only reads the first 36 characters of the string when converting to Guid.

***Clarification***

Following John Gathogo's comment about the `'{GUID}[gibberish]'` case (and after acceptance), I think I can expand the rule slightly.

1) If that string starts with `'{'`, then the *38th* **MUST** be `'}'` (try even leading and trailing spaces within - it won't work), otherwise conversion fails.  Then the 36 characters within are converted.

2) Otherwise, the first 36 characters are used.

So you can add `:)`, `<<` and `antidisestablishmentarianism` - after the 38th character in 1) or the 36th in 2), it makes no difference.

Comment: Not that am disputing your explanation but this **SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE GuidColumn = N'{2B375CD8-D210-463F-A2FD-EAFB0D643664}'** also works. So it does something stricter (beyond your FIRST 36 CHARACTERS explanation) when you add {} since then you cant enter other gibberish within {}. However, you can add gibberish after the closing }

Comment: @JohnGathogo that is a fair point will edit to something a little more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

A GUID is fixed width so the extra character is stripped during the type conversion;

```
declare @g uniqueidentifier = '2B375CD8-D210-463F-A2FD-EAFB0D643664#1'
select @g
>> 2B375CD8-D210-463F-A2FD-EAFB0D643664
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the query engine sees that it is a uniqueidentifier and internally just truncates at 36 characters - so anything afterward would simply be ignored. This also works fine, so it has absolutely nothing to do with the `#` sign:

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 'F9B8E808-E589-499B-8E57-22B7CBB2D63E ...
       and here is some extra garbage for fun');
```

Results:

```
------------------------------------
F9B8E808-E589-499B-8E57-22B7CBB2D63E
```